# Store multiple User data in User Claim Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I am using mvc 5, asp.net 4.5, EF 6 and identity 2.
I met a problem of inserting multiple user data into User Claim Tale
In my controller, after successful user creation i have the below code

```
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("FullName", user.FullName));
```

By this i can only insert `FullName` string in `ClaimType` column and `user fullname` in `ClaimValue`.
But i have insert `FullName`, `Email` and `UserType` and their respective values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add multiple claims you can just call AddClaimAsync for each claim you want to add:

```
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("Email", user.Email));
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("UserType", user.UserType));
```

Comment: also add an existance check